# Adding a legend on multiple kinds of plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm kind of struggling finding a solution about this specific problem and I'm pretty new to this ggplot2 thing.

So here's the deal : I'm trying to put a legend on multiple kinds of graphs in ggplot2 as shown here:

[image]

So I tried with this code :

```
ggplot(data) + 
 geom_histogram(aes(x = rain, y = ..density.., fill = group), bins = 15, color = 'lightblue', fill = 'lightsteelblue')+
 geom_density(aes(x = rain, fill = group), color = 'lightsteelblue', fill = 'lightblue', alpha=0.3)+
 scale_fill_manual(name = 'group',labels = c('Density histogram', 'Fitted pdf' ),
                values = c('lightsteelblue','lightblue'))+
 labs(x = "Rain" , y = "f(x)" , title = "Density histogram of the rain") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
 stat_function(fun = dnorm,
          args = list(mean = mean(data$rain),
                      sd = sd(data$rain)),
          col = "red", size = 1)
```

but it only gives me the graph without ANY legend shown

[image]

I really don't get how this legend thing works with ggplot.

As I said, I'm new to this, I really tried to search for answers and I might be doing things the wrong way or you might be horrified by my way of coding this (sorry about that haha).

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close, what you need to do is map the features you want into the aesthetics of each geom:

```
data <- tibble(day = 1:365,
           rain = brms::rskew_normal(n = 365, mu = 150, sigma = 30, alpha = -4))

 ggplot(data) + 
  
 geom_histogram(aes(x    = rain, 
                    y    = ..density.., 
                    fill = "lightsteelblue"), 
                bins  = 15, 
                color = "white") +
  
  geom_density(aes(x    = rain, 
                  fill  = "lightblue"), 
               color = "lightsteelblue", 
               alpha = 0.3) +
  
  stat_function(aes(color = "red"),
                fun  = dnorm,
                args = list(mean = mean(data$rain),
                            sd = sd(data$rain)),
                size = 1) +
  
  scale_color_manual(name = "",
                     labels = c("Normal pdf"),
                     values = c("red")) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(name = "",
                    labels = c("Density histogram", "Fitted pdf" ),
                    values = c("lightsteelblue", "lightblue")) +
  
  labs(x     = "Rain [mm]", 
       y     = "f(x)", 
       title = "Density histogram of the rain") +
  
  theme_bw() +
  
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

And that gives you as a result this image:

[image: histogram and pdf of the rain distribution]

Comment: Hi Ramiro, I noticed somehting weird when looking back to the code and the plotted graph. 
In the graph you showed, there's a mix between the colors in the legend and the colors of the graph. (Fitted pdf seems to be in lightblue in the legend and lightsteelblue on the graph and vice versa).

Could you help me with that ?

Comment: Oh, I just flipped them by accident. Check the order in the `scale_fill_manual` function, you can just change that to make them match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstration of some sort. There are two concepts in ggplot2 that are relevant and closely related here, that are:

- Aesthetics: a value to represent a graphical aspect of a plot
- Mapping: a link between a data value and an aesthetic

You can give aesthetics directly, by setting an aesthetic in the layer itself. For example, we can make a green histogram:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "limegreen")
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Now, if we're to make this aesthetic a mapping, we have to feed it through the `aes()` function. Note that the `mapping` is almost always the first argument of a layer, so we can omit the argument name.

```r
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = "limegreen"))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

However, as you can see above, this mapping doesn't really makes sense, even though it has a legend. This is because ggplot2 uses scales to represent mappings between data values and aesthetics. In this case, `"limegreen"` is seen as a *data*-value and not a graphical value. So when ggplot2 applies a palette to this value through a (default) scale, it comes out different than the graphical interpretation of this value. This link between data-values and graphical elements is displayed in the legend, which is a property of the scale.

Instead, it makes more sense to map a descriptive value to the aesthetic. We can then explicitly state the link between the data-value and aesthetic in the `scale_*()` function(s).

```r
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = "Histogram")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "limegreen")
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

If you've grasped the idea outlined above, it should then come naturally to extend the legend for other layers.

```r
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = "Histogram", y = after_stat(density))) +
  geom_density(aes(fill = "Density"), alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("limegreen", "tomato"))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you're using the `aes()` function, you can directly feed it symbols (names) of columns in your `data` argument (as you do too in your code). To be more precise, it is seen as an expression to be evaluated in the context of the `data` argument. That means that you can do things like this too:

```r
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = waiting * eruptions))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the theoritical details about legends ! 
This will defenetly be usefull for my next works on ggplot.
Have a nice day !